# Easy to use API builder

Tags: api, json

I would like to build a simple REST API to serve JSON data and some basic CRUD operations. My only other requirement is to have some sort of authentication. It would ideally allow me to enter a list of data fields, populate those fields and then expose them via a RESTful service with some form of authentication. It must be compatible with angularjs $http (which I thought was all RESTful services but apparently not).

I've been using Dreamfactory but it layers some complexity that I don't want for a simple project and I'd rather not spin up my own in Express + NodeJs (although that is my fallback right now).

Ideally, a point-and-click interface to build a REST API that I can host myself, realistically anything that achieves what's outlined in the opening paragraph.

Comment: I've found deployd. So far so good. Not sure about the authentication yet but easy point-and-click stuff.

Comment: Would that be http://deployd.com/ ?

Comment: @Mawg Yes, but since then I went with baasbox.com. Very easy to install and use. I deployed my production app behind an nginx reverse proxy to provide SSL. Slick setup.

Comment: Ir is allowed, encouraged even, to answer your own questions, so that others who have the same question in future will know what the answer is ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having built a project with Deployd, Baasbox and Parse since asking this question, Deployd is my goto for ***easy to use API builder***.

The authentication is not a robust as it could be (you need to limit each method on each collection via server side code) but it is easy and prototyping is super fast.

Personally, I've found the performance of Deployd and Parse to be better than Baasbox but that could be the setup I'm using. Parse is now defunct (with the exception of the open-sourced version) so Deployd is my recommendation.

(For the record, I do like Baasbox and Parse, I just *prefer* Deployd)

Answer (score -3):

How about [Swagger](http://swagger.io/)? It has tools for generating both server and client API code.

Comment: Please detail how it works.

Comment: "The goal of Swagger™ is to define a standard, language-agnostic interface to REST APIs which allows both humans and computers to discover and understand the capabilities of the service without access to source code, documentation, or through network traffic inspection." Not exactly an "easy to use api" tool. Someone may have implemented swagger in such a tool, but that is besides the point.